# How to set style of active page number in ASP.NET GridView Pager?

Tags: asp.net, css, pager

So I have GridView control and I would like to make a custom PagerStyle via css.

The problem is that I do not know how to change the style (color) of number indicating an active page. If I change the color property it changes a color of all page numbers. I would like to change color for active number and link numbers separately.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style should be like this:

```
.Pager a { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
.Pager hover { color: #AAFF00; text-decoration: none; } 
.Pager { color: #885454; text-decoration: none; background-color: #FFF7E7;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be after:

```
myElement:active {color: f00;}
```

But I'm not sure..